# When Creating Stacked Chart in SSRS, it is Showing Percentile

Tags: reporting-services, charts

In SSRS Report, when showing stacked chart data in Percentile I am getting numbers in 4 digits.

But when I choose normal type, I am getting numbers in 2 digits.

But, I want to show data in percentile.

Can you please help me on this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you showing a stacked chart, or a stacked 100% chart?  How are the values 6616% and 3383% being generated as in a 100% chart this should already b a percentage of 100...?

Comment: Thanks for reply, i am using stacked 100% chart, even i am also not sure , how its shows as 6616 in design time itself, when i use as percentage.

Comment: An easy solution would be to just divide it by 100 and display it as percentile. Or edit the lable display expression to add a "%" sign at the end.